# Git: how do I create new branches while another is active?

Tags: git, branch

I have an active branch (Branch A), but a slew of bugs have come forward, each requiring branches of their own (Branches B-D).

The strange thing is, I just can't find anything that explains how I keep Branch A, and then create Branches B through D, so I'm assuming it's not possible, which is even more strange if it is.

Earlier, with another repository, I tried creating a new branch while one was active and I lost those changes, so I am — understandably — nervous about this, given the sheer volume of changes in Branch A.

Comment: Commit changes, then branch. Isn't that enough? Remember: you _won't_ loose commited changes.

Comment: But how do I then return to those changes, once I commit them? I've tried that, too, and I can't get at them.

Comment: `git checkout A`. Do you want B-D to be children of A, or of master?

Comment: I have to assume I did something wrong before, because it's working.

Answer (score 2):

`git branch <branchname> <startpoint>` means you can create branches pointing to any given commit as a start point without checking out that branch.

```
C:\temp\testbranch>git branch
* master

C:\temp\testbranch>git branch first HEAD

C:\temp\testbranch>git branch second HEAD

C:\temp\testbranch>git branch
  first
* master
  second
```

In the above example I created two branches based upon the current commit but did not affect my working tree and I am still on master.

Comment: `git br` is not a valid git command. Surely you meant `git branch`